# How to apply aggregate with more data frame in r

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have 2 data frames, i want apply aggregate from all data frame,
my data is very large, so.. suppose my data is like:

```
data1
ID   Name    
1     A        
2     B       
3     C       
4     D       
5     E      
6     F       



data2
ID   Age
1      4 
2      5
3      12
4      53
5      2
6      8
```

after apply aggregate function, i want these result:

```
data_result
ID   Name    Age
1     A       4 
2     B       5
3     C       12
4     D       53
5     E       2
6     F       8
```

small notes:

1. data frame not have same length ( rows and cols ).
2. i was try to use group by function, but not work, show me this error:

   ```
   Error in UseMethod("group_by_") : 
   no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class 
   "character"
   ```
3. I don't need all columns from data frame, just 2 column for each one of them.
4. these task is very easy to implement in excel, but in r ???

any one can help me ?

Thanks

Comment: u can merge the data frames first and make the dataframe with equal length otherwise while aggregating u will get misleading values.

Comment: doesn't work, it seems: 'by' must specify a uniquely valid column

Answer (score 0):

You can merge the 2 dataframes together on ID with

```
merge(data1, data2, by="ID")
```

Comment: doesn't work, it seems: 'by' must specify a uniquely valid column

Comment: how exactly are you loading your dataframes to R? Can you give an example? What does `class(data1)` return?

Comment: return "data.frame"

Answer (score 0):

use merge() function in R as follows:

```
merge (x = dataframe1, y= dataframe2, by = "commom_column")
```

if data frames have different lengths its not a problem. For selecting columns, you can use select() function in dplyr package as follows:

```
dataframe1 <- select(dataframe1, c(column_names))
```

For your problem:

```
data1 <- select(data1, c(ID, name))
data2 <- select(data1, c(ID, Age))
merge(data1, data2, by = "ID")
```

Comment: Thanks, but when i use selec() it seems this error : must evaluate to column positions or names, not a double vector

Comment: can you share sample data i will sort it out